# Openejb rest integration tests with exception mappers

Tags: exception, junit, jax-rs, openejb

I'm writing some integration tests towards my jax-rs service where I have a set of exception mappers. So, when performing a given request I expect a certain response code based on the exception mapper. The problem is that I cannot get the exception mappers to be invoked when running in this environment.

My service which should throw a logicalexception in my test:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/baseCustomer")
public class BaseCustomerService {
    @EJB //this one gets mocked in the unittest
    private BaseCustomerManagerBean customerManager;

    @POST
    @Path("crud")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML})
    public Hkunde createCustomer(Hkunde newCustomer) throws LogicalException {
        //throws exception according to mocking
        return customerManager.createCustomer(newCustomer); 
    }
```

And the exception mapper:

```
@Provider
public class LogicalExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<LogicalException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(LogicalException exception) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).build();
    }
}
```

I set up my tests like this:

```
@Mock
private BaseCustomerManagerBean baseCustomerManager;
private HttpClient httpClient;
private BaseCustomerServiceClient client;

@Configuration
public Properties config() throws Exception {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.openejb.client.RemoteInitialContextFactory");
    properties.setProperty(OpenEjbContainer.OPENEJB_EMBEDDED_REMOTABLE, Boolean.TRUE.toString());

    properties.setProperty(DeploymentFilterable.CLASSPATH_INCLUDE, LogicalExceptionMapper.class.getName());
    properties.setProperty("openejb.jaxrs.providers.auto", "true");
    properties.setProperty("openejb.servicemanager.enabled", "true");
    return properties;
}

@MockInjector
public Class<?> mockitoInjector() {
    return MockitoInjector.class;
}

@Module
public EjbModule createModule() throws Exception {
    final StatelessBean bean = (StatelessBean) new StatelessBean(BaseCustomerService.class).localBean();
    bean.setRestService(true);

    final EjbJar ejbJar = new EjbJar();
    ejbJar.addEnterpriseBean(bean);

    final OpenejbJar openejbJar = new OpenejbJar();
    openejbJar.addEjbDeployment(new EjbDeployment(ejbJar.getEnterpriseBeans()[0]));

    EjbModule module = new EjbModule(ejbJar);
    module.setOpenejbJar(openejbJar);

    return module;
}
@Module
public Class[] exceptionMappers() {
    return new Class[]{LogicalExceptionMapper.class};
}

@Before
public void setup() {
    ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost("http://localhost:4204/BaseCustomerServiceTest");
    httpClient = new HttpClient(serviceHost);
    client = new BaseCustomerServiceClient(httpClient);
}

@Test
public void createCustomer_givenLogicalException_expectsLogicalException() throws LogicalException {
    Hkunde expected = new Hkunde(true);

    when(baseCustomerManager.createCustomer(expected)).thenThrow(new LogicalException("mock"));

    try {
        client.createCustomer(expected);
        fail("Expected LogicalException");
    } catch (LogicalException ex) {
    }

    verify(baseCustomerManager).createCustomer(expected);
}
```

So when I execute the test, my `client` will read the response code from the response and throw an exception based on this code.

The problem is that the exception mapper is never invoked, and I always receive a 500 internal server error, instead of the "forbidden" response. I'm guessing I need to add some more info when setting up the ejbjar or something like that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This example http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/openejb/trunk/openejb/examples/rest-applicationcomposer/src/test/java/org/superbiz/composed/rest/GreetingServiceTest.java (via http://rmannibucau.wordpress.com/2012/09/13/use-mockito-with-openejb/ ;-)) shows exactly what you want.

Add the following after `openejbJar.addEjbDeployment(...` and it should work.

```
final Properties properties = openejbJar.getEjbDeployment().iterator().next().getProperties();
properties.setProperty("cxf.jaxrs.providers", LogicalExceptionMapper.class.getName());
```

Here is a minimal working example (using openejb-cxf-rs 4.5.0 and openejb-core 4.5.0):

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient;
import org.apache.openejb.OpenEjbContainer;
import org.apache.openejb.config.EjbModule;
import org.apache.openejb.jee.EjbJar;
import org.apache.openejb.jee.StatelessBean;
import org.apache.openejb.jee.oejb3.EjbDeployment;
import org.apache.openejb.jee.oejb3.OpenejbJar;
import org.apache.openejb.junit.ApplicationComposer;
import org.apache.openejb.junit.Configuration;
import org.apache.openejb.junit.Module;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(ApplicationComposer.class)
public class RestWithExceptionMapper {

    @Configuration
    public Properties configuration() {
        return new Properties() {
            {
                setProperty(OpenEjbContainer.OPENEJB_EMBEDDED_REMOTABLE, Boolean.TRUE.toString());
            }
        };
    }

    @Module
    public EjbModule app() {
        final StatelessBean bean = (StatelessBean) new StatelessBean(MyResource.class).localBean();
        bean.setRestService(true);
        final EjbJar ejbJar = new EjbJar();
        ejbJar.addEnterpriseBean(bean);
        final OpenejbJar openejbJar = new OpenejbJar();
        openejbJar.addEjbDeployment(new EjbDeployment(ejbJar.getEnterpriseBeans()[0]));
        final Properties properties = openejbJar.getEjbDeployment().iterator().next().getProperties();
        properties.setProperty("cxf.jaxrs.providers", MyExceptionMapper.class.getName());
        final EjbModule module = new EjbModule(ejbJar);
        module.setOpenejbJar(openejbJar);
        return module;
    }

    public static class FooException extends RuntimeException {
    }

    public static class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<FooException> {

        @Override
        public Response toResponse(final FooException t) {
            return Response.ok("Objection!").build();
        }
    }

    @Path(value = "/test")
    public static class MyResource {

        @GET
        @Path(value = "/throw")
        public String throwException() {
            throw new FooException();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void checkServiceWasDeployed() {
        assertEquals("Objection!", WebClient.create("http://localhost:4204/RestWithExceptionMapper").path("/test/throw").get(String.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, but I've already tried all of this. Nothing seems to do it. I allways get a 500 exception which indicates the exception mapper has not been invoked.

Comment: Did you try my sample? It works in a simple maven setup:
<dependencies><dependency><groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId><artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId><version>6.0-4</version><scope>provided</scope></dependency><dependency><groupId>junit</groupId><artifactId>junit</artifactId><version>4.10</version><scope>test</scope></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId><artifactId>openejb-core</artifactId><version>4.5.0</version><scope>test</scope></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId><artifactId>openejb-cxf-rs</artifactId><version>4.5.0</version>...

Comment: If my sample does work with your setup, I think you should look at your test method, I did not use Mockito.